Multiple Android XML Previews (Design) in the one XML
Is there a way to create multiple previews of an XML layout without relying on an external LinearLayout for example.
Similar to the idea of @Preview in compose? Just curious if anyone has looked into this

Yes, you can create different XML layout files representing different variations or states of your UI. For example:
activity_main.xml
activity_main_dark.xml
activity_main_large.xml

Android Studio allows you to preview your layouts in various configurations such as different device sizes, orientations, themes, etc. You can easily switch between these configurations to see how your layout adapts like below
res/layout/activity_main.xml
res/layout-large/activity_main.xml
res/layout-night/activity_main.xml


Maybe we can't show multiple different states
